# Are coding cash bounties allowed on SuperUser?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I wish to offer payment for a 5 minute configuration via remote connection on my router to fix a configuration issue.

Are offers like this allowed on SuperUser?

Comment: In short... no.

Comment: Thanks, - I had a bad feeling that would be the case.

Comment: No..............

Comment: If the issue only requires 5 minutes of work, why not ask a question here and do the with yourself?

Comment: Because if you are so certain that it only takes 5 minutes then you clearly have the knowledge to do it yourself...

Comment: I know how, yes, but cannot make it work myself; so I would be looking for someone capable of using knowledge that I do not have and have not been able to find through searching and asking questions.

Answer (score 5):

#### Are offers like this allowed on Superuser?

Offers to pay someone to do some work have never been allowed on the Stack Exchange network:

> I totally appreciate your willingness to reward people's efforts, but offers of money are extremely frowned upon on Stack Overflow for various reasons - mainly out of the fear that allowing them would introduce very harmful dynamics into the community (ie. people tearing each others' eyes out for the $$$). If you're interested in previous discussion on the subject, see e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57850/pay-money-to-so-for-quick-support).
>
> You will have to look elsewhere in this specific regard.

Source [Is it alright to pay real money for useful help? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133794/267099), answer by [Pëkka](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/138112/p%c3%abkka)

Comment: Again, thanks, - I would not normally ask such a question, only I have hit a complete and total wall and can find no services, resources, or anything else that I can possibly use in order to resolve the problem I am having. As you may have noticed, my questions on the forum have a habit of attracting nothing by way of useful, usable, or constructive help.

Comment: So ask a question, provide us the required information to answer the question, and you will get an answer for free.  If it’s that’s easy you will get an answer on no time.

Comment: @Y Treehugger Cymru, Guru.com has per work-order service requests like this. I believe fieldengineer.com also has per work-order in person requests. I think if you asked your question with clarity, or in multiple clear questions for what you are trying to do, you could get help here.

Comment: Or maybe the thing you're trying to accomplish is *literally impossible*. Throwing money at an impossible problem doesn't make it possible. I'm just suspecting that you are *probably* trying to ask the impossible because (1) you won't tell us what it is and (2) you know enough about the problem to have done some research but have turned up no solutions.